# Why is correlation proportionate to the area of the intersection of the areas under the curves of the series?

Tags: data-visualization, autocorrelation, covariance

I've been staring at [this diagram from Wikipedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Comparison_convolution_correlation.svg), trying to understand (particularly autocorrelation):

[image: visualization of autocorrelation]

I see that the autocorrelation seems to be proportionate to the overlap between the graphs of the two series. But it's not clear to me why that is. And I don't know how well it generalizes, or what the diagram is assuming.

Comment: Not sure where exactly you are stuck, but "auto" means "self", so autocorrelation means that it's correlation of a function with itself. So, first `f*f` and then `g*g`, but the concept is exactly the same as in cross-correlation if you use two functions of the same shape.

Comment: I've got that much; I'm stuck on how the visual metaphor of the color-coded shaded overlap corresponds to the correlation. Covariance is more like the area of the product, which in certain special cases may be the same, and then it's all divided by stdev, which... I don't know, sorta relates somehow I guess.